# window.location.reload(); is working only when used with alert();

Tags: javascript, alert

I am using this code to reload my page on on checkbbox click-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showInactive(cb){
        $.get('showInactive', function(data) { }, 'json');
        alert();
        location.reload();
    }

    function hideInactive(cb){
        $.get('hideInactive', function(data) { }, 'json');
        alert();
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

This is working fine but when I remove the alert(); this code doesn't work.

Comment: `$.get('showInactive', function(data) {}, 'json');` doesn't seem to do anything useful.  What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: Site note: ``location.reload()`` may also reload the site from the cache. Use ``location.reload(true)`` if you want a real site reload...

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is how you call $.get. Look in to API https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
And I guess your location.reload() should be in callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var url = 'http://google.com';

    function showInactive(cb){
        $.get(url, function(data) {  
           location.reload();
        }, 'json');
    }
    function hideInactive(cb){
        $.get(url, function(data) {
           location.reload();
        }, 'json');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is helpful for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showInactive(cb){
       $.get('Use path of your file', function(data) {}, 'json');
       window.location.reload();
}
function hideInactive(cb){
      $.get('Use path of your file', function(data) {}, 'json');
      window.location.reload();
}

</script>
```